# Are there any issues with recovering bad sectors in a HDD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bad-sectors

I'm using the "HDD Regenerator" program, registered version. I want to recover the bad sectors in my HD that has Windows 7 Ultimate OS installed on it. I created a boot-able USB stick to be able to use this program.

I was wondering if, in recovering bad sectors I risk losing stability with the operating system or even if it won't start correctly. Do I run some risk of my system not wanting to start again after recovering the bad sectors?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, once a HDD has "bad sectors" you toss it in the bin. If you don't have backups and you're lucky, you might be able to recover the data from the drive. Continuing to use the drive is asking for trouble.

Comment: So I run the risk of my system not working again?

Comment: My system is working normally, but I did a check with "CrystalDiskInfo" and it accused problems in 3 sectors of my Hd

Comment: I wanted to use the HDD regenerator to recover without damaging the windows 7 file system

Comment: What's the exact name of the field CrystalDiskInfo reported? Pending sector count? Reallocated sector count? Something else?

Comment: Anyway, a pending sector count of >0 means your drive will very likely die soon. A reallocated sector count of >0 means your drive might die soon, but is less certain. (Pending means reallocations that have not yet succeeded, likely because you have no more spare sectors.) If this is a *change*, i.e. previously the count was 0, then you really should make sure your backups are up to date and replace the drive ASAP. Occasionally drives come from the factory with a couple reallocated sectors and hold stable.

Comment: Reallocated sector count, Current pending sector count, Uncorretable sector count

Comment: Yea if it's got both pending and uncorrectables, that's a strong indicator of imminent failure. Backup/clone and replace.

Comment: are these 3 sectors

Comment: I am already ready for data loss, I have already forwarded all the files to a pendrive

Comment: If I do not copy but no files into the Hd, can I extend the useful life of it ??

Comment: It's hard to say... often this kind of issue with a HDD indicates physical damage to the surface of the platter. Damage to the surface creates debris, which can damage surrounding sectors as the head passes over it. We're talking a head travelling at around 200km/h with a distance of a few *nanometres* over the platter surface. Even read-only access can further damage the drive. (There's other reasons a drive might reallocate, including a "weak" sector. But it's not really useful to try guessing - this is playing with fire.)

Comment: I'll have to wait for the death of HD. The good thing is that I have already backed up the files